# How to schedule multiple jobs in quartz scheduler using same trigger?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler in my spring project. I have to run a job after another job which is scheduled to run in every 15 mins? I cant run this job concurrently as both of this jobs have to access same mail account using different protocols(one to send:smtp and other to receive: imap) and it may cause problems. Please reply quickly, as its an urgent requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something with writing a job listener to recognize when the first job ends, and have it start the second.  But the solution first suggested by mindas is easier - wrap both your jobs in another Job implementation, which is the one you actually schedule.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a wrapper job class that launches second job after the first. You could then reuse separate jobs in the future if there will be any necessity.